# systemd resource control -- all users/root

Tags: systemd, limit, multiuser

I'm using Debian Bullseye with `systemd` 247. I have more than a hundred of users and I would like to enforce some limits using `cgroups`. I use `set-property`, which works as expected, for example for the memory and `AllowedCPUs` properties:

```
systemctl set-property user.slice MemoryHigh=300G
systemctl set-property user.slice MemoryMax=305G
systemctl set-property user.slice AllowedCPUs=9-64
```

The idea is to allow ordinary users to use 80-90% of the memory and most of the CPUs. The other 10-20% of the resources should always be available for other slices *and* for the `root` user (we were very liberal with setting the limits and recently we accidentally were fork-bombed by a student).

But the limits seems to also affect the `root` user and I cannot find a `user@0.slice` or anything like that. The idea is to allow the `root` to use the spare resources if thigs go wrong and always have some spare I/O, memory and CPU aside. `cgroups` seems like a good idea, because all switches are there. Could someone help and tell how to achieve this goal or give some general best practices with `systemd`/`cgroups` in multiuser environment? Or am I doing this completely wrong and this should be done differently?

#### Proposed answer (June 19th, 2022):

I think I managed to do it as described below, but I do not know if this is a "right" way to do it.

- `systemd` has a hierarchy within `drop-in` directories. In general, the more specific `drop-in` directories definitions override the less specific ones. (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#)
- `/etc/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/somethin.conf` will be overriden by `/etc/systemd/system/user-0.slice.d/something.conf`. Limits set in the former directory will apply to all users including `root`, but the definitions in the latter directory will override them and apply *only* to `root`. (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/user@.service.html)
- Using spare resources reserved for the `root` user requires a proper `root` login, for example on a TTY or through a console in case of a virtual machine. `sudo` or `su` are methods of elevating privileges, but do not hook into `cgroup` system (or at least I do not know how to do this). Using `sudo` or `su` the user is still bound by the `user-UID@` slice limits.

Kind Regards
~~
K.

Comment: It should be possible to set a hard limit by other limits, e.g. by the `ulimit -H` command in `bash`? Users cannot increase the hard limit.

Comment: Limits are set by a PAM module, `pam_limits` if I remeber correctly. I would like to use `cgroups`. And ther is no way to set I/O bandwith, IOPS and restrict CPUs using the PAM way (I think).

Comment: A few approaches can be found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/874274/systemd-per-user-cpu-and-or-memory-limits/874491 .  For example, user-N.slice is now templatable:   https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2556 (issue closed fixed).  See this answer in the link just given: https://serverfault.com/questions/874274/systemd-per-user-cpu-and-or-memory-limits/874491#980957

Comment: `set-property` is doing exactly this, creating a drop-in in the relevant directory. The problem I have is that this also affects the `root` user. I want to limit all users except `root`. I'll try `libpam-cgroup`